# How would I plot a graph of the number of non-NaNs per column in pandas?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I messed around with pd.count, but can't seem to get a dataframe with descending columns and counts in a way that can be plotted.

For example:

```
A   B   C   D
1   1   1   1
NaN NaN 1   1
NaN NaN NaN 1
```

I want to get it ordered by counts of all values minus the NaNs:

```
A 1
B 1
C 2
D 3
```

And then graphed into a line graph depicting counts. I've looked around and there doesn't seem to be any clear cut way. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, okay:

```
ser = df.count()
ser.sort(ascending=False)
ser.plot(ser.plot(kind='barh')
```

[image]

Comment: It works but would you know of a way to make it a descending plot of counts (i.e. most counts first, least counts last)? That is the thing I am having trouble with. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Sure, just call `sort`.